# Disable Java Hardware Acceleration in windows?

Tags: java, hardware-acceleration

I have some issues with my graphics card and I want to disable Hardware Acceleration for java apps. Everything that uses HA is displayed blurry.

I've seen some tutorials on how to set this parameter `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`

The problem is that the Java Control panel itself is using hardware acceleration and I cannot see anything in order to add this parameter.

**Edit:**
Went to java control panel in safe mode, added that parameter and problem continues..

**Edit2:**
Win 7 x64
JRE 6 update 30

**Edit3:** my deployment.properties (after your suggestions) file is:

```
#deployment.properties
#Sun Jan 08 01:12:04 EET 2012 deployment.version=6.0 
deployment.capture.mime.types=true deployment.browser.path=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe
#Java Deployment jre's
#Sun Jan 08 01:12:04 EET 2012 deployment.javaws.jre.0.registered=true 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.platform=1.6 deployment.javaws.jre.0.osname=Windows 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\javaw.exe 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.6.0_30 deployment.javaws.jre.0.osarch=x86 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.location=http\://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.enabled=true deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Dsun.java2d.d3d\=false 
deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=-Dsun.java2d.d3d\=false 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

still hardware acceleration is enabled.
Is there a possibility that applications can override these settings?

Comment: what version of java? what is the OS?  . . . If the program was using an OpenGl hardware acceleration, and it is blurry, I wonder if adjusting and locking manually your graphics cards opengl antialising (None) and asotropic (none) filtering things. . - Just from trying to read about it on the web now.  If it is text, some cleartype setting ?

Comment: Whatever uses hardware acceleration displays blurry image. Nothing is drawn actually, only artifacts. This is verified and it is not driver related but a hardware failure

Comment: That looks like the deployment properties file for the 32bit version, maybe there's another for 64bit

Comment: `Everything that uses HA is displayed blurry.` Why don't you fix this problem instead? :-/

Answer (score 5):

In my case the graphic corruption disappeared after adding the parameter `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`

[image]

Comment: It is obvious that java paths differ badly from post to post.

Comment: And the relation between java paths and runtime parameters is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that editing that setting in the Java Control Panel causes the file

C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

(Or whereever %appdata% points to)

to get a line:

deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=-Dsun.java2d.d3d\=false

That's per user settings, there's also a system settings option, that may be in All Users, not tested

Comment: What does Jre.`1`.args means?

Answer (score 1):

Had a very similar problem (in Linux), but the resolution to this problem was quite similar (disable hardware acceleration).

Rendering problems were even more serious:

[image: linux problems with hardware acceleration in java apps]

Setting the following parameters in order to disable hardware acceleration temporarily worked:

```
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using directx does not imply hardware acceleration is being used behind the scenes. You might want to resuce global acceleration if you see defective drawing (or update drivers)

Comment: In Win7 you cannot change the hardware acceleration if you have video drivers installed. Because I cannot do this, I have to disable acceleration one level below global-HW-acceleration.

Comment: If you use drivers from HCL (http://catalog.update.microsoft.com) the slider to reduce acceleration is back, and you can use official support channels to complain that you have to use it. Can you post a picture of "blur" you get?

Answer (score -1):

In the original post, there's:
`deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=-Dsun.java2d.d3d\=false`
`deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`
I think at the end it should be either "`=`" or "`\=`", but both in use could be why it still was not working.

Comment: You should validate this solution is correct and then edit and improve your answer